# How to add minimap on the sidebar in OpenLayers working by click

Tags: openlayers, geojson, sidebar

I have a simple OpenLayers map with a GeoJSON layer (several cities as points and labels) and a working sidebar where the properties of each city selected by mouseclick are displayed. In simplified form, this part of the code in main.js looks like this:

```
const idElement = document.querySelector("#id");
const coordsElement = document.querySelector("#coords");

map.on('click', function (evt) {
    let hit = false;
    const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
    //Filter for clicks aside from point
        if ( layer === mygeojsonLayer) {
            hit = true;
            return feature;
        } else {}
        });
    if (hit) {
        idElement.innerHTML = feature.get('id');
        coordsElement.innerHTML = feature.get('lonlat');
    } else {
        idElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        coordsElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
    if (!feature) {
        return;
    }
});

//I don't know where to put this:
const minimap = new Map({
    target: 'minimap', //<div id="minimap"> in index.html
    layer: new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
    }),
    view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: //???,
        zoom: 10,
    }),
});
```

In index.html the sidebar is a simple table with *div* and *span id="id"* and *span id="minimap"* in the rows. And apart from the minimap, everything works fine for me.

So where in main.js should I insert *const.minimap* part so that the minimap is in the sidebar and displays the selected city with a large zoom? So that the coordinates of the city are taken not from the location of the click on the main map, but from the properties of the city in the GeoJSON file?

I tried to insert *const.minimap* in various places inside *if* and *else* and the main problem was that the number of my minimaps on the sidebar grew with every click. Or, in other cases, I got no minimap at all - just two zoom buttons and OSM attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Mike, it works! The correct code is:

```
let minimap;

map.on('click', function (evt) {
    let hit = false;
    const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
    //Filter for clicks aside from point
        if ( layer === mygeojsonLayer) {
            hit = true;
            return feature;
        } else {}
        });
    if (hit) {
        idElement.innerHTML = feature.get('id');
        //coordsElement.innerHTML = feature.get('lonlat');
        const view = new View({
            projection: 'EPSG:3857',
            center: getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()),
            zoom: 10,
        });
        if (!minimap) {
            minimap = new Map({
                target: 'minimap', //<div id="minimap"> in index.html
                layers: [
                    new TileLayer({
                        source: new OSM(),
                    }),
                ],
            });
        }
        minimap.setView(view);
    } else {
        idElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        //coordsElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
    if (!feature) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the a global variable you can create it once and update it as required

```
let minimap;

map.on('click', function (evt) {
    let hit = false;
    const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
    //Filter for clicks aside from point
        if ( layer === mygeojsonLayer) {
            hit = true;
            return feature;
        } else {}
        });
    if (hit) {
        idElement.innerHTML = feature.get('id');
        coordsElement.innerHTML = feature.get('lonlat');
        const view = new View({
            projection: 'EPSG:3857',
            center: coordinate,
            zoom: 10,
        });
        if (!minimap) {
            minimap = new Map({
                target: 'minimap', //<div id="minimap"> in index.html
                layer: new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
            });
        }
        minimap.setView(view);
    } else {
        idElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        coordsElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
    if (!feature) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike! I think your code is correct and should work - but it doesn't. Still an empty window with "Zoom in" and "Zoom out" buttons instead of OSM-minimap. Although I imported OSM from 'ol/source/OSM' and there are no mistakes in F12-console.

Comment: Does the target div have a size set by css or style?  Is the sidebar always visible?  If visibility changes you may need to call updateSize https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize before the map will render.

Comment: Yes, the sidebar is always visible, and the target div have a size in px in style.css:
#minimap {width: 400px; height: 400px;}

Comment: I made a test column right in the middle of a page for a MapTiler map (called it 'testmap') with exact center-view coordinates and scale control. The problem is the same: after a click on main map I get zoom buttons in both windows (on the testmap and on the minimap in sidebar) and a scale-bar in the testmap. But no maps.

Comment: Do both maps use the EPSG::3857 view projection?

Comment: Now the minimap is displayed! The problem was with a "layer: new TileLayer({source: new OSM(),})," line. I changed it with "layers: [new TileLayer({source: new OSM(),}),]," and it worked! Thank you very much!
One last thing. Now the minimap displays a point where I clicked on the main map, but I want it to display an exact city's coordinates from its GeoJSON feature. I tried "center: coordsElement.innerHTML", but it shows Africa and, above all, doesn't change position after new click.
It looks like I have to create some kind of variable first.

Comment: `getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent())` would work for a feature of any geometry type