# How to add linestring in OpenLayers from GeoJSON property

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a map with a simple GeoJSON file layer (several towns) which has a 'bbox' property for each town. It is a point or a linestring. The GeoJSON file looks like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Rome","bbox":"12.486137, 41.891775, 12.487089, 41.891481"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.486137,41.891775]}}]}
```

Everything is fine when I use the usual way to add a GeoJSON file as Vector Layer. But how can I add a geometry from 'bbox' property of the file as a different layer? Should I add some brackets and commas?

I tried something like this but it didn't add anything:

```
const styleBBox = new Style({
    fill: new Fill(),
    stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#000',
        width: 1,
    })
});
const BBox = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource(),
    style: function (feature) {
        const coordinates = feature.get('bbox');
        styleBBox.getGeometry().getCoordinates(coordinates);
        return styleBBox;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify `geometry` in the style if you need to display a different geometry to the feature's own geometry.  You can convert a bbox to a polygon geometry using `fromExtent` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.fromExtent

```
const BBox = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource(),
    style: new Style({
      geometry: function(feature) {
        return fromExtent(
          feature.get('bbox').split(',').map(Number)
        ).transform('EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection());
      },
      stroke: new Stroke({
        width: 2,
        color: 'black'
      }),
    }),
});
```

Note that your bbox coordinates are non-standard and may be rejected - they should represent the SW and NE corners https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-5

Comment: Thank you, Mike! It works - if I specify my GeoJSON file as a vector source:

`source: new VectorSource({
 format: new GeoJSON(),
 url:'./towns.geojson',
}),
`
Now I just need to somehow specify several GeoJSON files - with different ranges of towns, which I select by clicking to display my [minimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76737836/how-to-add-minimap-on-the-sidebar-in-openlayers-working-by-click) in a sidebar.

Comment: It's strange, but all my attempts to add at least two different sources (e.g. `urls = [  './towns.geojson', './towns2.geojson'];`) lead to the fact that the bbox frame is not shown.

Comment: It works! I combined your answer, Mike, with your other [adviсe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420516) about multiple vector sources in vector layer.